# find mean in array in a list with 'int'

Tags: python, arrays, list, standards, mean

I have a example code like this

```
[('Name1',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name1',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name1',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name1',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name2',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name2',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name2',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])),
('Name2',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])))]
```

it have 2 set name1 and name2, then I want to find mean and std of each set. How can I perform?

I want the result like

```
[('Name1',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ]))
('Name2',
(array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0. ]),
array([ 0.x ,  0.x  ,  0.x,  0.x   ,  0.x ,  0.x, 0.x ,  0.x,  0.x  ])))]
```

Comment: What did you try? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Ahh, this question makes a lot more sense now that you've updated it.

Comment: @NickBraunagel It's still "gimme teh codez"

Answer (score 0):

Lemmie know if this works for you:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# first setup dummy data
data = []

for n in ['Name1','Name2']:
    for x in range(0,3):
        arr1 = np.array([random.uniform(0.01, .999) for x in range(0,10)])
        arr2 = np.array([random.uniform(0.01, .999) for x in range(0,10)])
        data.append( (n, (arr1,arr2))  )
```

dummy data:

---

```
print data

[('Name1',
  (array([ 0.42829892,  0.74412464,  0.10539088,  0.20311414,  0.58198844,
           0.46101113,  0.68292586,  0.81267642,  0.99532936,  0.3405878 ]),
   array([ 0.1067372 ,  0.88300393,  0.50167696,  0.09278143,  0.82566162,
           0.61846205,  0.75793834,  0.05615872,  0.1392957 ,  0.47040616]))),
 ('Name1',
  (array([ 0.41027949,  0.62382025,  0.54786748,  0.05291593,  0.38031568,
           0.97634268,  0.25089338,  0.15540717,  0.04407247,  0.66016435]),
   array([ 0.98352017,  0.75861331,  0.69127009,  0.75296262,  0.88320749,
           0.56094834,  0.50017185,  0.32840499,  0.1303067 ,  0.58507772]))),
 ('Name1',
  (array([ 0.66889542,  0.19254057,  0.26710317,  0.21664814,  0.3263039 ,
           0.4874041 ,  0.32197665,  0.23848192,  0.13399946,  0.30235608]),
   array([ 0.98900843,  0.4776821 ,  0.22797999,  0.37936821,  0.64405839,
           0.90948502,  0.34509434,  0.02213441,  0.05807166,  0.07292462]))),
 ('Name2',
  (array([ 0.79995558,  0.06922339,  0.41487208,  0.05105112,  0.33803899,
           0.42719283,  0.70650005,  0.79217882,  0.26335194,  0.2441568 ]),
   array([ 0.04865805,  0.98418529,  0.24103137,  0.03807163,  0.4250344 ,
           0.62093819,  0.84126019,  0.24216516,  0.49392502,  0.56105416]))),
 ('Name2',
  (array([ 0.87176419,  0.02085948,  0.11908837,  0.91108143,  0.14798886,
           0.27183369,  0.0126322 ,  0.17154493,  0.73486529,  0.47225411]),
   array([ 0.73480276,  0.96634328,  0.5483403 ,  0.0465088 ,  0.83981127,
           0.45037624,  0.08671031,  0.86267524,  0.10546492,  0.39057744]))),
 ('Name2',
  (array([ 0.52060301,  0.57423193,  0.87839692,  0.2456256 ,  0.42934864,
           0.15498324,  0.71696378,  0.33675668,  0.47241556,  0.81932544]),
   array([ 0.50506363,  0.75726219,  0.6067386 ,  0.63605477,  0.74871351,
           0.33845177,  0.21416992,  0.95949599,  0.40044606,  0.3922125 ])))]
```

### Find mean and std of arrays:

```
results_mean = []
results_std = []

for n in list(set([i[0] for i in data])):
    results_mean.append(   (n, (np.mean([list(j[1]) for j in filter(lambda x: x[0] == n, data)],axis=0)))   )
    results_std.append(   (n, (np.std([list(j[1]) for j in filter(lambda x: x[0] == n, data)],axis=0)))   )
```

Yields:

---

```
print results_mean

[('Name2',
  array([[ 0.73077426,  0.22143826,  0.47078579,  0.40258605,  0.30512549,
           0.28466992,  0.47869868,  0.43349348,  0.49021093,  0.51191212],
         [ 0.42950815,  0.90259692,  0.46537009,  0.24021173,  0.67118639,
           0.46992207,  0.38071348,  0.68811213,  0.33327867,  0.44794803]])),
 ('Name1',
  array([[ 0.50249128,  0.52016182,  0.30678717,  0.1575594 ,  0.42953601,
           0.64158597,  0.41859863,  0.4021885 ,  0.39113376,  0.43436941],
         [ 0.6930886 ,  0.70643311,  0.47364235,  0.40837075,  0.78430916,
           0.69629847,  0.53440151,  0.13556604,  0.10922469,  0.37613616]]))]

print results_std

[('Name2',
  array([[ 0.15147736,  0.25024294,  0.3124976 ,  0.36823043,  0.11719871,
           0.11149915,  0.32958645,  0.26244379,  0.19290536,  0.23648017],
         [ 0.28516675,  0.10302499,  0.16041298,  0.27992449,  0.17798465,
           0.11614983,  0.32978675,  0.31779982,  0.16554739,  0.07998089]])),
 ('Name1',
  array([[ 0.11789523,  0.23681223,  0.18280682,  0.07420011,  0.1100322 ,
           0.23695385,  0.18914698,  0.29223347,  0.42880528,  0.16042222],
         [ 0.4146191 ,  0.16953569,  0.1901734 ,  0.27029695,  0.10191693,
           0.15256329,  0.17027193,  0.13706339,  0.03635633,  0.21945436]]))]
```

Comment: i got error 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (23,) (22,) ' @Nick Braunagel

Comment: That is because the arrays are not the same length. Are they suppose to be the same length?

Comment: It must be because it generate through the same code @Nick Braunagel

Comment: I think you need to figure out if the arrays should be the same size or not. You cannot achieve the desired outcome identified in your question until the arrays are the same size.   The outcome will be different if the arrays are a different length. Come back when you know more.